# Having trouble getting bootstrap-datepicker to show date and time in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have been able to render the bootstrap datepicker for month day and year but unfortunately I can't get it to render for month day year AND hour minute selection.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Bob

Comment: What have you tried? Typically, including the code that you are using or what you have tried will increase the chances of getting a useful answer. We aren't here to do the work for you, just to help you with specific questions you may have.

Comment: Sorry for not supplying the code as I was expected to be pointed to a working example

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [Bootstrap 3 Datetime Picker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)?

I've used it and it seems pretty straight forward.

You add the following CSS and JavaScript to your page (you should already have jQuery and bootstrap scripts in place):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Note: It also uses [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Then on my form I used the following HTML and Razor markup:

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.BlogPost.PostedOn, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BlogPost.PostedOn, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "text" })
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-calander"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Simple as that and it seems to work quite well. See this [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/phgbf65t/6/) I created.